# Facebook like button skewing Google Analytics page time load

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-like

I have a pretty well performing site with an average load time of `0.97` thorough all the pages. However, we've recently added a Facebook like button to our homepage and it resulted in load time of `2.09` for that particular page.

It is definitely not a crucial issue to focus on. I could for example insert the like button with js after the page loads, but then it would have to be an iframe, limiting the click measurements (GA social plugins).

Is there a way to render the like button after a page loads and still retain the API, allowing click tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading facebook after onload:

```
<script>
(function(w, d, s) {
  function go(){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], load = function(url, id) {
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.src = url; js.id = id;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    };
    load('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=272697932759946&xfbml=1', 'fbjssdk');
    load('https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js', 'gplus1js');
    load('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', 'tweetjs');
  }
  if (w.addEventListener) { w.addEventListener("load", go, false); }
  else if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent("onload",go); }
}(window, document, 'script'));
</script>
```

Source: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/why-loading-third-party-scripts-async-is-not-good-enough